# Some basic c# programs that you recommend for a beginner

Tags: c#

As i am new to programming... What are the basic c# programs that i should go through to know about c# programming.... Any sample programs...

Comment: " the basic c# programs" ??? I think you want to post a question about learning C#? Start by searching SO, which has lots of similar questions

Comment: @Mitch any similar question on this site?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you try searching yourself. Being able to search is a pre-requisite for being able to program....

Comment: @Mitch as i am a new user so i asked you to do so... If it is wrong i am sorry

Comment: i think SO should introduce ANDing of tags. tried searching `C# beginner` on http://stackoverflow.com/tags, no results.  can only search either `beginner` or `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find largest number in an array.
Many people fail to do this in an interview.

Comment: You must be kidding. Failing that means you are not able to code anything in my POV. +1 for being weird.

Comment: Can i give it a try? `var max = myArray.Max();`. Do I get the job? :-)

Comment: How can you do less the O(n) if you need to check n elements?

Comment: @Steven Can you walk us through the miraculous sorting algorithm that can sort an arbitrary array in O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn some basic [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Oriented_Programming) concepts to program in C#. Search Google to find more resources on this topic. Then, skim through [this site](http://www.csharp-station.com/). [This](http://www.mastercsharp.com/) is also a good one. After that, do some projects on your own. You will learn C# only if you apply it regularly. You don't have to learn the whole language. Just concentrate on the task at hand and try to learn how to do that in C#. In this way, you will have less trouble in learning.

Remember, Google is the way to find resources on any topic nowadays, including C#. Use it well.

Hope that helps......

Answer (score 1):

I always recommand to start with a **Calculator**

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this microsoft examples [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08e3d5f8-033d-420b-a3b1-3074505c03f3&displaylang=en#filelist) and another [link](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/csharp/csharp-language-basics.html)

Also this would be [best place](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/default.aspx) to start with.

You can also search on SO and google to start learning c#.

Answer (score 0):

Google C# tutorial , you will find lot of link. 
http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/12/c-tutorial-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Start writing a calculator by using c#.

Comment: As long as it's not one of these: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/OMGWTF-Finalist-02-The-FileSystemHashMapNotepadCalculator.aspx ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to learn to do a GUI (Winforms or WPF), I would suggest doing a simple TicTacToe game. Whenever I learn new GUI tools, I start with TicTacToe and it always helps me get a good grasp on how to interact with the controls.

Answer (score 0):

While there are tons of resources on programming with C# (see other answers/SO search/Google), I think it's important to know what your goals are with 'programming'? Are you trying to solve a complex mathematical challenge, building a web application, developing desktop applications or games? Every one of these take a different approach.

I agree with @Sayem Ahmed that you should understand Object Oriented Programming concepts to start working with C#.

Start small, then gradually challenge yourself by making your projects more complex, the trick is knowing what you're doing at all times. If you don't understand your own code (anymore), you might have gone too fast and get lost in confusion.

If you're really new to programming, I also recommend getting a book (yeah I know, old-school), there are plenty of topics on SO to point you to a good one. When well written, they usually provide a nice coherent chunk of information instead of billions of loose code scraps.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Hello World program

To make you comfortable with data structure, try this beginner programs:

- Swap Hello and World
- loop Hello World's individual characters and display it slowly.  use Thread.Sleep(500) in between
- reverse string "Hello World" to "dlroW olleH" (apparently C# don't have built-in reverse string function)
- jump ahead to extension methods, convert your reverse string routine to extension method
- Get an input, if user input 3, it will display 'o World Hell', if user input 1 display 'ello WorldH', in short make a string rotator function

  thinking... will post this answer first, then will add some later

Or you could try the new Hello World, [make your own blog engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471940/why-does-every-man-and-his-dog-want-to-code-a-blogging-engine)